# The def function I called doesn't implement

Tags: python, function

So, I'm basically trying to make a program to calculate the mean of five numbers. I called a def function but it doesn't do anything. I run the project on cmd and just it sits there and makes another input line. Bam, no calculation, no anything. There doesn't seem to be a problem with the code because the compiler doesn't point one out. Feel free to be critical and rude, it's all good with me. And I'm a beginner, so I might have made some real stupid mistakes. :)

```
numberNumber1 = input("Please enter 1st number.")
numberNumber2 = input("Please enter the 2nd number.")
numberNumber3 = input("3rd please")
numberNumber4 = input("4th now")
numberNumber5 = input("5th finally")

def mean (operation) :
operation = (numberNumber1/5 + numberNumber2/5 + numberNumber3/5 + numberNumber4/5 + numberNumber5/5)
final = "The mean of these 5 numbers is " + operation
print (final)
return ;
```

Comment: Check that the function block is properly indented.

Comment: This code makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: You didn't __call__ your `mean` function. It doesn't need any parameters, so change it to `def mean():` and add `mean()` at the bottom of the file.

Answer (score 0):

First your indentation looks wrong.
Then you don't want to have `operation` as argument since you are computing it, the arguments should be your numbers. Or probably nothing, and instead put your number inputs inside your function (and you need to call it after you define it). Finally no `;` in python (and this `return` statement is not necessary, although not a problem either).

Answer (score 0):

1. Your indentation is wrong.
2. You are never actually calling the function.
3. `input` returns a string, so you will have to convert the numbers to float.
4. Since `operation` is a float, you can't simply concat it to create the `final` string.

Your code should basically be changed to this:

```
numberNumber1 = float(input("Please enter 1st number."))
numberNumber2 = float(input("Please enter the 2nd number."))
numberNumber3 = float(input("3rd please"))
numberNumber4 = float(input("4th now"))
numberNumber5 = float(input("5th finally"))

def mean(numberNumber1, numberNumber2, numberNumber3, numberNumber4, numberNumber5):
    operation = (numberNumber1 + numberNumber2 + numberNumber3 + 
                 numberNumber4 + numberNumber5) / 5
    final = "The mean of these 5 numbers is {}".format(operation)
    print(final)

mean(numberNumber1, numberNumber2, numberNumber3, numberNumber4, numberNumber5)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors here is a fix.

```
numberNumber1 = float(input("Please enter 1st number: "))
numberNumber2 = float(input("Please enter the 2nd number: "))
numberNumber3 = float(input("3rd please: "))
numberNumber4 = float(input("4th now: "))
numberNumber5 = float(input("5th finally: "))

def mean(numberNumber1 ,numberNumber2,numberNumber3,numberNumber4,numberNumber5):
    # Parameters are not needed but in case you change variables now this won't break the function
    mean = numberNumber1 + numberNumber2 + numberNumber3 + numberNumber4 + numberNumber5
    mean = mean / 5
    print("The mean of these numbers is: " + str(mean))

mean(numberNumber1,numberNumber2,numberNumber3,numberNumber4,numberNumber5);
```

The errors are:

- You have never called the function
- Incorrect Indentation for function
- Python can't convert int/float to string without being told to do so causing an error

Comment: Yep, just realized, horrible indentation. Thanks, buddy. I did forget to call the function and convert it to string after the operation.

Answer (score 0):

```
numberNumber1 = input("Please enter 1st number.")
numberNumber2 = input("Please enter the 2nd number.")
numberNumber3 = input("3rd please")
numberNumber4 = input("4th now")
numberNumber5 = input("5th finally")

def mean() :
    operation = (numberNumber1/5 + numberNumber2/5 + numberNumber3/5 + \
    numberNumber4/5 + numberNumber5/5)
    print("The mean of these 5 numbers is %s" % operation)
    return operation;
print(mean())
```